# iPod Nano wake screen sometimes shows music instead of Clock

Tags: sleep-wake, ipod-nano

I've recently purchased a band from Lunatik to use my iPod Nano as a watch.

To do this, I've gone into Settings > Date and Time > Time on Wake and put this ON.

At first, this worked as expected, showing me the watch face when I hit the 'on' button.
But after I've played some music on the Nano, now it sometimes shows me the music application (even though it's **not** playing) instead of the Clock.

I've checked and the setting 'Time on Wake' is still on.

Anyone know how I can avoid this behaviour and always get the Clock when I hit the 'on' button?

Comment: Does it open the music app or the music player on the lock screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well answer this.

I've found out that it depends on what screen you had active before the iPod goes to sleep. If it goes to sleep with the Music screen, that apparently gets priority over the clock on waking (even if you have checked the 'time on wake' setting).

A workaround I've found is navigating to any Settings screen before putting the iPod to sleep. Upon waking up, he'll 'default' back to the Clock then... Apparently the Music screen has a higher 'priority' than the Settings screen, go figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing a playlist or album you have to play the whole thing to the end or just fast forward. Then the player shuts down and reverts back to the clock.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out that if you are only using it as a watch like I am, then simply delete any music on it and it will always wake up in watch mode.  Not sure what to do if you want music. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Selecting the Radio app the music app goes off and it's done, there is no more priority